# Understanding debug log for failed ssh connection with key pairs

Tags: macos, ssh, openssh

I've two personal computer (mac) with same pair of ssh keys.

After one update on machine B, I can't access to machine A

I execute this steps:

- Syncro with rsync .ssh dir from machine A to B
- Now files `.ssh/id_rsa`, .`.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, `.ssh/authorized_keys` are the same.
- Delete in two machines `.ssh/know_hosts`
- Try and fail

SSH with debug

```
abkrim {~/.ssh} $ ssh -vvv abkrim@192.168.1.69
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "192.168.1.69" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.69 [192.168.1.69] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/abkrim/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/abkrim/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/abkrim/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/abkrim/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/abkrim/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/abkrim/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/abkrim/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/abkrim/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.69:22 as 'abkrim'
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:sXVosdAMvhsJ6H17TSIVVRq/fWmo5YG6EHyKm9ARWaw
The authenticity of host '192.168.1.69 (192.168.1.69)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:sXVosdAMvhsJ6H17TSIVVRq/fWmo5YG6EHyKm9ARWaw.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.1.69' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /Users/abkrim/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fa807c00440)
debug2: key: /Users/abkrim/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /Users/abkrim/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /Users/abkrim/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0)
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/abkrim/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
Authentication failed.
```

But in other order (machine A to machine B) work fine.

On remote mahcine, server SSHD show this:

```
tail -f /var/log/system.log | grep sshd
May  1 20:42:22 iMac-2 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.openssh.sshd.DE639EE5-7072-4B2F-950A-11C38130393B[9492]): Service exited with abnormal code: 255
```

Comment: To know for sure why the ssh server (sshd on the machine you were trying to connect to) rejected your authentication attempt, you’ll probably need a verbose log from sshd on the machine you were trying to connect to.

Comment: @Spiff Edited my question, for show log: `Service exited with abnormal code: 255`

Comment: To get proper debug info out of sshd, you'll need to stop launchd from running sshd, then manually invoke "sshd -ddd…" this causes sshd to stay connected to your terminal and send debug log messages to stdout.

Comment: A lot of thanks... start with `/usr/bin/sshd -ddd` show my several problems with read `/etc/ssh/*_key`'s `not hostkey available

Answer (score 3):

According to the official spec for the SSH protocol (RFC 4252), the authentication packets have the following values:

```
SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST    50
SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE    51
SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_SUCCESS    52
```

This means that `debug3: receive packet: type 51` indicates that the server rejected the key.

Comment: Realizing that "type 51" was a failure code was extremely helpful just now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Spiff to show me way to debug problem.

Stop sshd

```
sudo launchctl stop com.openssh.sshd
```

Start sshd on shell manually

```
sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -ddd
debug2: load_server_config: filename /etc/ssh/sshd_config
debug2: load_server_config: done config len = 290
debug2: parse_server_config: config /etc/ssh/sshd_config len 290
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:42 setting AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:58 setting PasswordAuthentication yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:83 setting UsePAM yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:108 setting AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:114 setting Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/sftp-server
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:124 setting XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_7.6, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:Pyv2GkZBE5DYoepXu5yWZ4Y+QAEoPzuU56EisU1D5rI
debug1: private host key #1: ssh-dss SHA256:GY5LotzDXNJ7nXuryDS5HehCcpBgYDieJbIbUnzBU/c
debug1: private host key #2: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:sXVosdAMvhsJ6H17TSIVVRq/fWmo5YG6EHyKm9ARWaw
debug1: private host key #3: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:toO00XtxCi+zs7CU1KE0cHpJ3QvO+YSIlVxnkq8rnaE
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-ddd'
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 4 IPV6_V6ONLY
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Bind to port 22 on :: failed: Address already in use.
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0 failed: Address already in use.
Cannot bind any address.
```

This show a problem with port in use

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right answer either. I think if you stop `sshd` but don't unload the whole `launchd` job, then `launchd` itself will still keep a listener open on TCP port 22 on `sshd`'s behalf. So you need to do `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist` before you run `sshd -ddd…`.

Comment: Thanks. But problem is other. Your reply show me the way. Problem is a bug on system sshd with apple. Confirmed by support. SSH is already unload, but port 22 is in use. Also verify ps aux|grep -i ssh, and not is on ps. After this , communicate with Appalce support, and say me is a bug, get solution on next update, thanks

Comment: What I’m trying to tell you, and you and Apple Support are missing, is that launchd holds listeners open on ports on behalf of network daemons like sshd that launchd auto-launches. So port 22 is open by launchd on sshd’s behalf. If you do `sudo lsof -i :22` you’ll see that I’m right.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue in macOS catalina.

After stopping `sshd` and unloading `launchd` via `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist` I then manually started `sshd` using `/usr/bin/sshd -ddd` and then attempted to ssh into the machine from a different computer.

Looking at the output, I saw `Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory...` which indicated a permissions issue.

I corrected my permissions issues by running the following items on my home and .ssh directories.

```
chmod go-w ~/
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

After that, I was able to login using key pairs.

Alternatively, I could have set `sshd_config` such that:
`StrictModes no`, but I wouldn't suggest that.